# How does mysql store multiple blank spaces?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a PHP script that displays an HTML form that allows a user to enter data in a `<textarea>` and store it in MySQL.

The user (me) entered multiple lines of text in the `<textarea>` that included `\n`, `\r`, and 4 consecutive space characters (to indent a list I was making).  For example:

```
first line of text:
second line of text:
    (A) some task
    (B) another task
```

When the form was submitted, the content was stored correctly in MySQL, including the hidden `\r`, `\n`, and the four space characters before `(A)` and `(B)`.

However, `var_dump()`-ing the data in PHP shows this:

```
first line of text.\r\nsecond line of text:\r\n (A) some task\r\n (B)another task
```

The four space (U+0020) characters I entered do not appear between the `\r\n` and `(A)`, there is only one space  character.  I even ran the data through a string to hex converter and it only showed one `U+0020` before each (A) and (B) instead of four `U+0020`s.  But, when I re-open the form to edit the data in the `<textarea>`, the content shows up correctly, just I had entered it originally, with the 4 spaces before the `(A)` and `(B)`.

My scripts all are behaving correctly and there is no problem.  I'm just wondering: **How is MySQL and `<textarea>` able to detect the 4 spaces, but `var_dump()` only detects one space?**

Here is what I have tried to detect the 4 spaces in PHP, with the data stored in a PHP `$Variable`:

- `var_dump($Variable)`-ing immediately before and after storing the data in MySQL, before/after `stripslashes()`, and before/after outputting the data to `<textarea>` and all each `var_dump()` does not detect detect the 4 spaces.
- **`strpos($Variable)` detects the 4 spaces.**
- `print_r($Variable)` does not detect the 4 spaces.
- `echo $Variable` does not detect any hidden characters, except for single spaces (not the 4 consecutive spaces)

Comment: When var_dumping something, the result on the screen is treated as any other html, i.e. with runs of spaces collapsed to one space. Put it in a container and give the container `white-space:pre-wrap`.

Comment: This is the answer.  I up-voted this comment.

Comment: @MrLister has to post it as an actual answer if you want to accept it; comments aren't "acceptable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you var_dump a variable, it is shown the same HTML.

If you want to show the spaces, you can add [`white-space:pre-wrap`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/).

The `white-space` CSS property determines how whitespace inside an element is handled. To make words break within themselves, use overflow-wrap, word-break, or hyphens instead.

With pre-wrap, sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.